# Splitting one CSV into multiple files based on field value

Tags: bash, csv

I do have a CSV which looks like this*:

```
system,subject,value1,value2
example.org,thing 1,100,4
exmaple.org,thing 2,90,0
example.com,thing 1,200,0
example.com,thing 5,10,10
```

The header us actually not included, but shown here to make it easier to read the example.

And I want to split that up into two files:

example.org.csv with:

```
thing 1,100,4
thing 2,90,0
```

example.com.csv with:

```
thing 1,200,0
thing 5,10,10
```

My current solution works this way:

```
while read line; do
  SYSTEM=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f1)
  NOTTHESYSTEM=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2-)
  echo "${NOTTHESYSTEM}" >> "${SYSTEM}.csv"
done <$INPUT
```

But this is working very inefficient and doesn't perform well with bigger files.

In numbers this means that a 52050 line/ 9 MB file needs about 250 secounds to finish the split.

Any suggestions how to improve the script above are welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk` it will be simpler:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $2, $3, $4 > $1 ".csv"}' "$INPUT"
```

**Verification:**

```
cat example.org.csv
thing 1,100,4
thing 2,90,0

cat example.com.csv
thing 1,200,0
thing 5,10,10
```

Comment: Much faster - thank you. This now runs in 0.3s instead of 250s.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a gzip stage using this method,  so that all the output files would be gzipped?

Comment: Just redirect output into a file and call `gzip` to zip it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, assuming you have a reasonably small number of systems:

```
cut -d, -f1 file.csv | \
    sort -u | \
    while read -r system; do
        fgrep -w "$system" file.csv | cut -d, -f2- >"$system".csv
    done
```